# Find a document by its _id and then make an aggregation (left join)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 tables (clients and type_clients), I need to do a findOne and then an aggregation (left join).
Here is the code making the aggregation :

```
var client = await Client.aggregate([
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "idTypeClient": {
            "$toObjectId": "$idTypeClient"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "type_clients",
          "localField": "idTypeClient",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "type_clients"
        }
      }
    ]);
```

The result of the aggregation is this :

```
    [{"_id":"644d07b750c766f2e55a99d4","name":"Apple","idTypeClient":"644d01b7ad65ba68ad69da4c","website":"http://www.apple.com","type_clients":[{"_id":"644d01b7ad65ba68ad69da4c","label":"Type B","__v":0}]},

{"_id":"646a08f35dd43ed3e780ee62","name":"nom","website":"site","idTypeClient":"6436cbaa7f6ab8abdf83d87c","__v":0,"type_clients":[{"_id":"6436cbaa7f6ab8abdf83d87c","label":"Type A","__v":0}]},

{"_id":"646a0b915dd43ed3e780ee69","name":"c","website":"c","idTypeClient":"644d01baad65ba68ad69da4f","__v":0,"type_clients":[{"_id":"644d01baad65ba68ad69da4f","label":"Type C","__v":0}]}]
```

To add a "WHERE _id" = clause, I added a "match". But it doesn't work, the result is empty.

```
var client = await Client.aggregate([
      { $match: { "_id" : "646a0b915dd43ed3e780ee69" } },
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "idTypeClient": {
            "$toObjectId": "$idTypeClient"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "type_clients",
          "localField": "idTypeClient",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "type_clients"
        }
      }
    ]);
```

Any clue? When it comes to aggregation I'm a bit lost.

Thanks

Comment: how are your _id saved? as objectid or string? if _id of client collection is string  then ur query should work

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bOx5OpNW3-P

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Require mongoose package

   `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`
2. When you compare id, the type should always be of ObjectId.

   `{ $match: { "_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("646a0b915dd43ed3e780ee69") } },`